# jQuerySplitter control/kendoSplitter not resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, kendo-ui

If you resize the bottom pane, the view will shrink, and can't return to the original size.  Also, even though I have the size is set to 100%, the view won't take the entire screen. I've tried setting static sizes on the middle and bottom panes vertical section like this:

```
$("#vertical").kendoSplitter({
    orientation: "vertical",
    panes      : [
        {
            collapsible: false,//toolbar should be a set height and unable to be collapsed
            resizable  : false,
            size       : "50px"
        },
        {
            collapsible: false //main section, not collapsible, but resizable
        },
        {
            collapsible: true, size: "200px"
        }
    ]
});
```

But whenever that is done, a scrollbar appears on the pane, with the rest being hidden under whitespace.

jsFiddle : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6rjKe/)

Example of jQuery Splitter/kendoSplitter: [here](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/splitter/index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following css definitions for `mainView`:

```
#mainView {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

This makes the main container occupy 100% of the screen an resize when windows resizes.

See it in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/6rjKe/1/) modified JSFiddle.

Comment: That did it thanks, mind if I ask why it worked? Are the fields after position forcing it to have no padding with those edges?

Comment: Of course I don't mind... The fact is that in my browser (Chrome) the central area (`main_pane`) was rendered with 0px high and I've started _removing_ part of your styles. Then I realized that you were not using what uses to make an area grow and shrink with the page (the styles that I defined in `mainView`). Solving this, solved the `main_pane` and the I returned other changed styles to previous state. Conclusion: It's recommended to define `position: absolute` and set `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` to 0 for making a `div` adjust to its container size.